# Variable args reflection method invoke

Tags: java, methods, reflection, invoke, variadic-functions

The user will type the method to be called and the arguments of it. i.e.:

- function1 param1
- function2 param1 param2
- functionN param1 param2 .. paramN

Assuming all parameters are strings, I save all the input of the user in a stack of strings:

```
LinkedList<String> stack = new LinkedList<String>();
```

And then, using reflection I obtain the method:

```
SpreadSheet myClass = new SpreadSheet();
Class objClass = myClass.getClass();
Method meth1 = objClass.getDeclaredMethod(stack.pop());
```

I'm missing the part of invoking the method with the variable args remaining in the stack. Any help ?

Comment: The java reflection tutorial by Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: Looks like you lack the object reference where to invoke the method.

Comment: You need to call `meth1.invoke(objectWithThatMethod, arguments)` where in case of static method `objectWithThatMethod` can be `null`. Now you simply need to create `Object[] arguments` array and fill it with rest of elements from your stack. It shouldn't be that hard since you know `size()` of stack.

Comment: @adrian objClass.getDeclaredMethod(stack.pop()); will never work,you are only passing method name,you need to pass Class Objects also to narrow down on method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objClass.getDeclaredMethod(stack.pop());`  will return a method which has the name returned by `stack.pop()` and which takes no arguments.

To correctly use `getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)` you need to pass the method name and correct number of Class Objects,you are passing Objects of Class String

The correct way would be:-

```
    LinkedList<String> stack = new LinkedList<String>();
    SpreadSheet myClass = new SpreadSheet();
    Class objClass = myClass.getClass();
    String methodName = stack.pop();
    Class<String>[] parameterTypes = new Class[stack.size()];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(parameterTypes,String.class);  // fill the array with String.class Object
    Method meth1 = objClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
    meth1.invoke(myClass, stack.toArray());
```

Comment: You pop the stack twice and don't use method name.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Copy that :)